# Multiple in-place substitutions in one line

Tags: ruby

What is the most idiomatic way to do multiple in-place substitutions on a string when none of the patterns being replaced are guaranteed to have a match?

For instance, say I have an array of strings and I want to replace "sad" with "happy" and "goodbye" with "hello" in each one:

```
a = ["I am sad", "goodbye for now"]

# This will work:
a.map! do |s|
    s = s.gsub(/sad/,"happy").gsub(/goodbye/,"hello")
end
# So will this:
a.each do |s|
    s.gsub!(/sad/,"happy")
    s.gsub!(/goodbye/,"hello")
end
# This will fail when s does not match /sad/:
a.each do |s|
    s.gsub!(/sad/,"happy").gsub!(/goodbye/,"hello")
end
```

The first option seems a little bit silly, since logically I'm trying to do an in-place substitution rather than a re-assignment. The second option is okay, but my aesthetic sense tells me that it seems wrong to be required to turn the substitution into two sequential statements, particularly in cases when only one or the other substitution is expected to be successful (which, ironically, is exactly the case that causes the third version, which looks "right" to me, to fail). Also, it's probably wrong to use `each` destructively as I'm doing here, but if I used `map!` instead, I'd need to add `s` as the final line in the block to ensure I don't accidentally make `nil` entries when substitution fails, which seems almost sillier than the first option.

I'm guessing the reason the `(g)sub!` methods return `nil` when no substitution is done is because that makes them convenient for use in logical constructs, which is admittedly a very good reason (especially since the non-destructive versions obviously must return "true" values no matter what).

So...I know this is really very little more than a minor aesthetic quibble, but is there a better way than the two (working) ways I've shown? If not, is there any reason to prefer one over the other (beyond my intuitive aesthetic preference for the second version)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to create a `replacement_hash` as below :

```
replacement_hash = { "sad" => "happy", "goodbye" => "hello"}
a = ["I am sad", "goodbye for now"]
Regexp.union(replacement_hash.keys) # => /sad|goodbye/
a.map { |s| s.gsub(Regexp.union(replacement_hash.keys), replacement_hash) }
# => ["I am happy", "hello for now"]
```

If *in-place* replacement needed, do as below :-

```
a.each { |s| s.gsub!(Regexp.union(replacement_hash.keys), replacement_hash) }
```

Comment: Good solution. Though technically he wanted in-place replacement, so you could change `a.map .. s.gsub` to `a.each ... s.gsub!`.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers Thanks.. Please don't delete your comment.. as it is important.. :-)

Comment: ....huh. I didn't realize that `(g)sub(!)` could use a hash for key-to-value replacement. Thank you.

Comment: Some oddities, though: (1) Why don't the single-argument versions of `(g)sub(!)` check to see whether their argument is a hash or a pattern? Explicitly specifying the pattern when you provide a hash seems redundant, since I would imagine that in most cases you'd want the pattern to be what it is here, i.e., `Regexp.union(r_hash.keys)`. For `gsub!(r_hash)` to return an enumerator makes little sense to me. (2) Apparently (at least in Ruby 2.0), the keys of `replacement_hash` must be strings rather than symbols. Any idea why?